# Upper casing of accented characters in Perl - Still confused

Tags: perl, utf-8, uppercase

I have a variable in my Perl script that holds the first letter of a string, where that string is encoded in utf-8. I assign this variable in the course of reading from a file. I am trying to upper case the letter pointed to by this variable. However, the following appears to have no effect:

```
# $first_letter is already assigned to "á". Now we apply uc to it
$first_letter = uc $first_letter;
```

However, I do the following test in my script

```
if ( $first_letter eq "á" ) {
    my $first_letter1 = "á";
    printf(
        "Upper case first_letter: %s Upper case first_letter1: %s \n",
        encode_entities( uc $first_letter ),
        encode_entities( uc $first_letter1 )
    );
}
```

and it prints out:

```
Upper case first_letter: &aacute; Upper case first_letter1: &Aacute;
```

So we can see that when I explicitly assign a variable to "á", applying uc to it works, but something about the variable I have assigned by reading my file is different (even though $first_letter eq "á")

How can applying uc to $first_letter and $first_letter1 yield different values if I have ensured that they are equal to each other?

Comment: Does your script `use utf8`?  Have you tried comparing `$first_letter` directly against `$first_letter1`?

Comment: I suspect that your example doesn't show exactly what is happening in the program

Comment: When I compare $first_letter and $first_letter1 they are eq before applying uc to them, but they are no longer eq after applying uc to them. And yes my script does use utf8. And as far as I know, I am representing this situation accurately.

Comment: It might be helpful to see what `$first_letter` actually contains. Consider showing the additional output generated by `use Devel::Peek; print Dump $first_letter, Dump $first_letter1;`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I saved the following as UTF-8:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use utf8;
use open 'IO', ':utf8', ':std';

my $first_letter = 'á';
if ($first_letter eq 'á') {
    my $first_letter1 = 'á';
    printf "Upper case first_letter: %s Upper case first_letter1: %s\n", 
        uc $first_letter,
        uc $first_letter1;

}
```

Output in a UTF-8 terminal:

```
Upper case first_letter: Á Upper case first_letter1: Á
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are explicitly assigning the values for $first_letter and $first_letter1. I am reading $first_letter from a file. I suspect that's where the problem lies, but that's why I did the eq test to try to ensure that what I was reading from the file is really á

Comment: @egilchri: How did you open the file? Did you specify the encoding?

Comment: I just checked, and this is what I have    open my $inh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $in
 or croak "Could not open $in for input: $OS_ERROR";

Comment: This might be relevant. In the context of the debugger, uc does have an effect. I apply uc to $first_letter and I can then print the results. 
However, I can't get this same effect to occur in my script. So what's different about my debugger environment and the script environment?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to my own question. The "uc" operator started working as desired when I added the line:

use 5.014_001;

near the top of the .pm file where all this was being executed. I don't quite understand this, since I was executing the script with Perl version 5.16 all along. But something about that "use" line changed the behavior of "uc".